# How to add marker in google maps predefined place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently i'm making a program which allow user to get coordinate from googlemaps. The program get the location of place by using mouse pointer. If there is no predefined place there, it should get a correct coordinate, however if there is something (train, restaurant, hospital) i cant get the coordinate. How can i get coordinate for that predefined place?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var map,marker;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
    geocode(event.latLng);
  });
}
function geocode(position) {
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': position}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[1]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: position,
                  map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          } else {
             alert('No results found');
         }
     } else {
         alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
     }
  });    
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/waniqoso/1/edit). Do you find any difficult feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your code, then i change the zoom level to 14. I find "Uluru-Kata Tjuta National Park", but when i clicked on tree icon, it won't add mark. How can i add mark on that place?